# How to change only one of the facet borders when using facet_grid

Tags: facet-grid

I've got a `ggplot` where I'm using `facet_grid`, what I want is for the inner facet borders to have a different color than the outer ones. Can I use `element_rect()` somehow, or is there another way?

This is what I currently have:

[image: Currently having this]

This is what I need it to look like:

[image: This is required]

Thanks!